# twitter direct messgae

Tags: twitter

Hai, I am using oauth for display followers list,Now I want to send message to any one who is NOT my follower of my twitter,is it possible with oauth  using PHP.

Comment: Spamming is not the way to get followers.

Comment: This would be a great way to get banned from Twitter.

Comment: Twitter would become even more useless than it currently is (if that's even possible)

Comment: you can only send the direct message to them who are your follower ...... How can you send the message whom you dont know in any socialsite is this possible ehhh ....

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to send a direct message to a non-follower, period.

Comment: hi..i want to send direct message to on twitter, can you help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You want to send a message to every single Twitter user who isn't following you?

This is not possible, and *never* will be.

Comment: @Zabba: Can you imagine Twitter enabling this?

Comment: I didn't mean about Twitter enabling this, but I just threw into the wind that maybe there are ways to do it w/o twitter enabling it? I'm not an expert on twitter but.

Comment: If so, Twitter will block it.

Comment: hi..i want to send direct message to on twitter, can you help me out.